# Permission Denied when trying to restore .dump file postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying the following command load schema and data from .dump file :

```
psql proj1 -f /Users/utkarshatri/Desktop/proj1/mymyunsw.dump
```

but it says permission denied.

[image]

the folder containing the .dump file has read write permissions for postgres

```
total 101728
drwxr-xr-x@ 4  utkarshatri staff 136      24 Mar 05:41 ./
drwx------@ 23 utkarshatri staff 782      24 Mar 06:18 ../
-rwxrw-rw-@ 1  utkarshatri staff 52080321  8 Mar 00:30 mymyunsw.dump*
-rwxr--r--@ 1  utkarshatri staff 2130      8 Mar 00:30 proj1.sql*
```

simple cat on terminal works but returns permission denied on postgres commandline
[image]

How do I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just try a simple `cat` on that file and see if you still get the same error?

Comment: @MattClark simple cat on terminal works but returns permission denied when using postgres commandline

Comment: Can you provide the _relevant_ output of `ls -alF proj1`, please include the entries for `.`, `..`, and the `.dump` file.

Comment: @MattClark 
total 101728
drwxr-xr-x@  4 utkarshatri  staff       136 24 Mar 05:41 ./

drwx------@ 23 utkarshatri  staff       782 24 Mar 06:18 ../

-rwxrw-rw-@  1 utkarshatri  staff  52080321  8 Mar 00:30 mymyunsw.dump*

-rwxr--r--@  1 utkarshatri  staff      2130  8 Mar 00:30 proj1.sql*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be not with the *current* directory, but the directory, one level above:

```
drwx------@ 23 utkarshatri staff 782      24 Mar 06:18 ../
```

This is showing that *only* your user has the permissions required to enter the project directory. Try running this

```
chmod a+rx ../
```

This will change the permissions such that *anyone* on the system can open and look inside the directory, but still, only you will be able to *write*.